# How to implement multilabel classification on UTKFace dataset using Tensorflow and Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, multilabel-classification

Basically I am trying to predict Age, Gender and Race from [UTKFace dataset](https://susanqq.github.io/UTKFace/) by building multilabel classification model using Tensorflow and Keras. This is what my preprocessed dataset looks like . I have couple of questions here

1. What should be the class_mode in ImageDataGenerator `class_mode="multi_output"` or `class_mode="raw"` and why? I tried both `class_mode="multi_output"`(Throws  `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape')` and `class_mode="raw"`( throws `InvalidArgumentError:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 15745024 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 294912. [[node sequential_1/flatten_1/Reshape (defined at <ipython-input-22-9c3a9b687782>:4) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2086]`)
2. What should be the loss function for each of the features(Age, Gender, Race) and why?

[image: preprocessed data]
Here is what I have done so far

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Activation, MaxPool2D, Dropout, Flatten
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mimg
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

!tar -xvf /content/UTKFace.tar.gz
!tar -xvf /content/crop_part1.tar.gz

!mv /content/UTKFace/* /content/data
!mv /content/crop_part1/* /content/data

contentdata = []

import os
for i in os.listdir("data"):
  content = i.split("_")
  if ((content[0].isnumeric()) and (content[1].isnumeric()) and (content[2].isnumeric())):
      contentdata.append([content[0],content[1],content[2],os.path.join("data",i)])
  #print(content[2])
  #imgarray = plt.imread(os.path.join("data",i))

data = pd.DataFrame(contentdata,columns=["Age","Gender","Racevalues","Filepath"])

data.head(10)

data.Age = data.Age.astype('float')
data.Gender = data.Gender.astype('float')
data['Racevalues'] = data['Racevalues'].astype('float')
data.Filepath = data.Filepath.astype('string')

data.dtypes

train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.1)

testdatagenerator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. /255)
testdata = testdatagenerator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=test,directory=None,x_col="Filepath",y_col=["Age","Gender","Racevalues"],class_mode="raw")

traindatagenerator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. /255,shear_range =0.2,zoom_range=0.2,horizontal_flip =True)
traindata = traindatagenerator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=train,directory=None,x_col="Filepath",y_col=["Age","Gender","Racevalues"],class_mode="raw")

#model = []

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 input_shape=(100,100,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer="Adam",loss="binary_crossentropy",metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(traindata,
                   steps_per_epoch=100,epochs=100,
                   validation_data=testdata,
                       validation_steps=100,batch_size=20)
```

Can someone guide me through this?

Answer (score 2):

First you should use to_categorical (one hot encode) in your labels:

```
df['Age'] = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(df['Age'])
df['Gender'] = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(df['Gender'])
df['Racevalues'] = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(df['Racevalues'])
```

And so:

```
traindata = traindatagenerator.flow_from_dataframe(
    train, 
    IMG_PATH, 
    x_col='Filepath',
    y_col=["Age", "Gender", "Racevalues"],
    target_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
    class_mode="multi_output",
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE
)
```

The last step is to adapt your model to 3 outputs:

```
input_node = base_model.get_layer('last_layer_model').output

x = Flatten()(input_node)
age_output = Dense(n_age_labels, activation='softmax', name='age')(x)

x = Flatten()(input_node)
gender_output = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='gender')(x)

x = Flatten()(input_node)
race_output = Dense(n_race_labels, activation='softmax', name='race')(x)

model = Model(base_model.input, [age_output, gender_output, race_output])

model.compile(optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=1e-4), 
              loss = {
                  'age': 'categorical_crossentropy',
                  'gender': 'binary_crossentropy',
                  'race': 'categorical_crossentropy',
              }, 
              metrics = {
                  'age': 'accuracy',
                  'gender': 'accuracy',
                  'race': 'accuracy'
              }
             )
```

P.S.: In this example, I'm using a classifier approach to predict age, you can change this for regresssion. Using classifier, you should complement the prediction with:

```
output_indexes = np.array([i for i in range(0, 101)])
apparent_predictions = np.sum(age_predictions * output_indexes, axis = 1)
```